# NGINX показать index.php из другого каталога

Tags: php, nginx, php-nginx

Всем привет. Есть сервер Nginx. На нем есть три каталога: /var/www/wp/(тут CMS WordPress),  /var/www/php5/(тут файл index.html и index.php) и /var/www/php7/(тут тоже файл index.html и index.php)

Вот стандартный default конфиг:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::] 80 default_server;

    root /var/www/wp;
    index index.php index.html;

    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    } 

    location ~ \.php$ {
         include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
         fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    } 
    
    location ~ ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/ {
         root /var/www/;
         try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/index.html;
    } 
}
```

При запросе localhost открывается сайт на wordpress.
При запросе localhost/php5 открывается файл index.html в папке php5
При запросе localhost/php7 открывается файл index.html в папке php7

А как сделать, чтобы вместо html файлов открывался файл php?
пишу try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/index.php; - появляется ошибка типа 404.

Как заставить сервер работать с файлами php в разных каталогах?

Comment: Смотря как у Вас работает скрипт. Сейчас Вы пытаетесь попадать по путям в надежде, что в каждой папке из пути в адреcе, что указан, есть index.php. Если у Вас он только один и является точкой входа, но тадо убрать подстановку — `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;`

Answer (score 0):

Было найдено следующее решение.

Нужно было папки php5, php7 создавать ВНУТРИ папки wp. А в секции location для этих папок нужно было дописать wp в root.

Вот исправленный и рабочий вариант:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::] 80 default_server;

    root /var/www/wp;
    index index.php index.html;

    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    } 

    location ~ \.php$ {
         include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
         fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    } 
    
    location ~ ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/ {
         root /var/www/wp;
         try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/index.php;
    } 
}
```